# I can't put metadata into next.js

Tags: next.js

I'm programming a site in next.js with node.js API and mongodb database. and I got to the metadata part. When reading on the internet you need to do some operations on the page.js or layout.js file but I don't have these files in my project.
These are my directories.
Src:
Component:
...
Page:
_app.js
_ducument.js
index.js
Style:
global.css

I've tried creating layout,js or page.js in pretty much every directory and putting metadata there but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `pages` directory as opposed to the `app` directory the documentation you are viewing is about. Use the pages directory documentation on metadata [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing).

[image: switcher component in docs]

As you can see from the screenshot above, you explicitly need to set the dropdown to the corresponding directory, due to the new router introduced in Next.js 13+.